# Calculating a normalized anomaly using a a climatology from a multiyear netcdf file

Tags: python, python-xarray, rolling-computation, quantile

I have a multiyear netcdf file. I am trying to calculate normalised anomaly of this dataset `(X - mean(X)) / std(X)` at each grid point.

mean(X) = daily climatology of data i.e mean of 1st jan, 2nd Jan, ...31 dec. The final file has 366 time steps.

std(X)  =  std climatology of data. The final file has 366 time steps.

Before calculating the normalised anomaly the mean is smoothed using the rolling 95 quantile.

The dimension of `(X-mean(X))` and `std(X)` are not matching !!!!!

Below code, I am using

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

ds = xr.open_dataset("chirps-v2.0._merge_1981_2019.days_p05.nc")

xtime = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=366)

# Calculate mean climatology and std climatology
gb = ds.groupby('time.dayofyear')
clim = gb.mean(dim='time')
std_clim = gb.std(dim='time')

# Change time dimension from dayofyear to time
good_clim = clim.rename({'dayofyear': 'time'})
good_clim["time"] = xtime

good_std = std_clim.rename({'dayofyear': 'time'})
good_std["time"] = xtime


# Rolling quantile (0.95) on mean climatology
rol_clim_P95 = good_clim.precip.rolling(time=7, center=True).construct('tmp').quantile(.95, dim='tmp')

# Change time dimension from to time to dayofyear
rol_clim_P95_dayofyear =  rol_clim_P95.groupby('time.dayofyear')

rol_clim_P95_dayofyear_mean = rol_clim_P95_dayofyear.mean(dim='time')


anom = (gb -  rol_clim_P95_dayofyear_mean)/std_clim
```

Comment: Please state clearly which line is throwing the error and give the full trace back

Comment: Thank you
the error is coming from this line 

`anom = (gb -  rol_clim_P95_dayofyear_mean)/std_clim`

Comment: please always provide the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors. and to clarify information in your post, please [edit] the post to clarify rather than commenting. thanks!

Comment: `The dimension of (X-mean(X)) and std(X) are not matching !!!!!` What are their dimensions?

Comment: Thank you Michael

The number of time steps in the initial multi-year file is 14244. 

The calculation of the climatological mean and standard deviation gives files of 366 time steps (taking into account leap years). 

The climatological average is such that the 1st of January are averaged together, the 2nd of January together, ...., the 31st of December together. 

Another thing I'm thinking about is replicating the climatological mean and standard deviation. Then create a data set where we remove February 29th for non-leap years. 
So we will have files with the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

When you group on time.dayofyear and reduce over time, you do indeed change the dimensions. The time dim is replaced by a new dim, `dayofyear`.

The solution to this is to reindex the dayofyear data using xarray’s advanced indexing so the climatology variables you create are repeated for the corresponding days of year for each year in the time dimension:

```py
# Calculate mean and std climatology
gb = ds.groupby('time.dayofyear')
clim = gb.mean(dim='time')
std_clim = gb.std(dim='time')

# Rolling quantile (0.95) on mean climatology
rol_clim_P95 = clim.precip.rolling(dayofyear=7, center=True).construct('tmp').quantile(.95, dim='tmp')

# reindex to full time series
rol_clim_P95_time = rol_clim_P95.sel(
    dayofyear=gb.time.dt.dayofyear
)

std_clim_time = std_clim.sel(
    dayofyear=gb.time.dt.dayofyear
)

anom = (
    (gb - rol_clim_P95_time)
    / std_clim_time
)
```

This works because the indexer `gb.time.dt.dayofyear` is a DataArray with the values giving days of the year in [1, 365] matching the coordinate of the climatologies but the dimensions and coordinates are the full `time` dim, so when used to select into a climatology the arrays are reshaped to match the full time dimension.

See the xarray docs on [More Advanced Indexing](//docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) for more info.

Comment: I think it should be `rol_clim_P95_time = rol_clim_P95.sel(
    dayofyear=ds.time.dt.dayofyear)`, otherwise I get the error `AttributeError: 'DataArrayGroupBy' object has no attribute 'time'`